# Sensible exit statuses in the Unix environment; SIG_* range

Tags: c, shell, unix

Exit statuses can be integers inside of`<0,255>`.
Some exit statuses are "standardized" via the `sysexits.h` file, and some will be created by a POSIX shell e.g.:

```
126 Command invoked cannot execute

127 "command not found"

128 Invalid argument to exit

128+n Fatal error signal "n"
```

Regardless of standardization, this makes statuses from 126 included upwards insensible to use because if a shell is used, the caller won't be able to distinguish whether an exit status that's `>=126` was generated by the callee or by the shell.

Does that insensible range span all the way up to 255 (in other words, what is the range of signal identifiers)?
`sysexits.h` has

```
#define EX__MAX 78  /* maximum listed value */
```

What does it mean? Does it only refer to the `sysexits.h` file or should programs never exit with an exist status `> 78`? (If so, why?)

What is the safe range for exit codes in Unix that a program invoked by a POSIX shell can use so that the caller can be sure the exit code was generated by the callee and not by the shell?

Comment: `sysexits.h` is not part of POSIX. It's a convention of BSD systems, not of POSIX.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks for clarifying that. However, I believe the conversion between termination signals and shell generated exit statuses or conditions like "cannot execute", "not found" and shell generated exit statuses is POSIX, and that's what the main subject of this question is.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer to this is to start by reading the man page "man 2 wait". This documents the integer return value, which contains a bitfield for the exit code, and a separate bitfield for the signal which caused the exit.

On BSD-derived Unixes, the signal is a 7-bit field in the least significant bits. The 8th bit indicates whether a core file was dumped, and the next 8 bits are the exit code. There is no real standard for the exit codes except that 0 means success and 1 is the most common failure.

However, you should check your systems header files (usually sys/wait.h) for definitions, and use the macros documented in the wait(2) man page to extract parts.

Answer (score 1):

See this http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

According to the table shown in link, exit codes 1 - 2, 126 - 165, and 255 [1] have special meanings, and should therefore be avoided for user-specified exit parameters.

Comment: These "special" codes are the opinion of the authors of _bash_. BSD has different opinions: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits and Linux does not hold those opinions: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html - so I repeat, there is no real standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could do that in a shell script. Well, you could take a look at the `State` value in `/proc/(pid)/status` but I never relied on it, so I can't be 100% sure it will always work.

My way of differenciating a "normal" return value from a signal is to use `wait(2)` and the macro `WIFSIGNALED`. Here's an example of how to use them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t p;
  int s;

  p = fork();
  if (p == 0)
    execl("./the_program_to_test", "");
  else
    {
      wait(&s);
      if (WIFSIGNALED(s))
        printf("Signal detected\n");
      else
        printf("No signal detected\n");
    }
  return (0);
}
```

You could write a "wrapper" to give your shell script a composed information (exit status of the program + whether is was generated by a signal or not)